# regex matching - java

Tags: java, regex

I've a requirement -
I've a sentence, `he is a good programmer, he won 865 competitions, but sometimes he dont. What do you think? All test-cases should pass. Done-done?`
Number of words in that sentence is 21.
Here is another example:
`jds dsaf lkdf kdsa fkldsf, adsbf ldka ads? asd bfdal ds bf[l. akf dhj ds 878  dwa WE DE 7475 dsfh ds  RAMU 748 dj.`
Number of words: 21
Word definition:
[image: defn]

I wrote a java code to count words in a string.

```
public static int howMany(String sentence) {
    // Write your code here
        // int count = 0, i = 0;
        // if (sentence == null || sentence.isEmpty()) {
        //     return 0;
        // }
        // boolean isWord = false;
        // int EOL = sentence.length() - 1;
        // char[] chars = sentence.toCharArray();
        // for(i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
        //     if(Character.isLetter(chars[i]) && i != EOL) {
        //         isWord = true;
        //     } else if (!Character.isLetter(chars[i]) && isWord) {
        //         count++;
        //         isWord = false;
        //     } else if (Character.isLetter(chars[i]) && i == EOL) {
        //         count++;
        //     }
        // }
        // return count;
        
        // StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
        // return st.countTokens();
        int count = 0;
        String regEx = "[\\w-]+";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(sentence);
        while(match.find()) {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

My code doesn't count words properly, here is another example:
`b? Dl )B 4(V! A. MK, YtG ](f 1m )CNxuNUR {PG?`
Number of words: 5.
But my code prints 12. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why would it be 5?

Comment: What do you consider a "word"? Please provide the specifications.

Comment: In this example, `jds dsaf lkdf kdsa fkldsf, adsbf ldka ads? asd bfdal ds bf[l. akf dhj ds 878  dwa WE DE 7475 dsfh ds  RAMU 748 dj.`, `bf[l.` won't count as a word because it is invalid. Numbers like `748` aren't words. So expected output is `21`. My code prints `26`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni: Can you clarify a bit more e.g. what are 5 words here `b? Dl )B 4(V! A. MK, YtG ](f 1m )CNxuNUR {PG?` ?

Comment: In this example, `b? Dl )B 4(V! A. MK, YtG ](f 1m )CNxuNUR {PG?`, these are the words: `b?`, `Dl`, `A.`, `YtG` and `lm`. So 5 words. I hope you got it now

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry... I read `1m` as `lm`. Sorry for confusion. `MK,` is a word, `1m` isn't a word.

Comment: I have predefined test case which says that for that big string, `jds dsaf lkdf kdsa fkldsf, adsbf ldka ads? asd bfdal ds bf[l. akf dhj ds 878  dwa WE DE 7475 dsfh ds  RAMU 748 dj., bf[l.`, number of words is 21. Naturally my code fails to read it accurately. My code prints as 26. I'm unable to figure out right regex for this.

Comment: Here is the definition of word... 
https://ibb.co/YNZSd0K

Comment: Use `\b\p{L}+(?:-\p{L}+)*\b`, in  Java, ``"\\b\\p{L}+(?:-\\p{L}+)*\\b"``, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/e4dP98/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex doesn't work, please run it against all test cases that I posted. Look at `word definition` which I posted

Comment: @AjayKulkarni: Please provide list of `21` words as per your definition

Comment: `jds`, `dsaf`, `lkdf`, `kdsa`, `fkldsf`, `adsbf`, `ldka`, `ads`, `asd`, `bfdal`, `ds`, `akf`, `dhj`, `ds`, `dwa`, `WE`, `DE`, `dsfh`, `ds`, `RAMU`, `dj`, these are the 21 words according to `word definition`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for your customised word matches:

```sh
(?<!\S)\pL+(?:-\pL+)*(?=\pP*(?:\h|$))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6CGybi/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\S)`: Negative lookbehind to assert that we don't have a non-whitespace before current position
- `\pL+`: Match 1+ of any letter
- `(?:-\pL+)*`: Match 0 or more such 1+ letter separated with a `-`
- `(?=\pP*(?:\h|$))`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have 0 or more punctuation characters followed by a whitespace or end of line

**Java Code:**

```
final String s = "jds dsaf lkdf kdsa fkldsf, adsbf ldka ads? asd bfdal ds bf[l. akf dhj ds 878  dwa WE DE 7475 dsfh ds  RAMU 748 dj., bf[l.";

final String re = "(?<!\\S)\\pL+(?:-\\pL+)*(?=\\p{P}*(?:\\h|$))";

final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(re).matcher(s);

int count = m.results().count();
//=> 21

/*
// or to get list of matching words
List<String> words = m.results()
   .map(MatchResult::group)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

// => [jds, dsaf, lkdf, kdsa, fkldsf, adsbf, ldka, ads, asd, bfdal, ds, akf, dhj, ds, dwa, WE, DE, dsfh, ds, RAMU, dj]
*/
```

Comment: Awesome... thank you very much... `Word definition` was pretty confusing, aint it?

Comment: Indeed it was. Just a tip that always include all the details in your question upfront to avoid any guessing game.